# Python read line by line and keep indents

Tags: python

I have to read a Python file and find a specific line, then replace a text and then write back to the file.

When I check back the file, I am getting an indent error.

How to fix this issue?

```py
reading_file = open("myfile.py", "r")
    new_file_content = ""
    for line in reading_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        if (stripped_line.find('siteip = ') != -1):
            stripped_line = "siteip = \"%s\"" %(siteip)
        new_line = stripped_line
        new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
    reading_file.close()
    writing_file = open("myfile", "w")
    writing_file.write(new_file_content)
    writing_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: `strip` discards the indentation; there's no reason you need to do that. If you want to discard just the newline that ends the line, use `line.rstrip('\n')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```py
with open("test.py", "r") as fp, open("myfile.py", "w") as fw:
    for line in fp:
        idx = line.find('siteip = ')
        fw.write(line[: idx] + "siteip = \"%s\"" %(siteip) + "\n" if idx != -1 else line)
```

Using list comprehension

```py
with open("test.py", "r") as fp, open("myfile.py", "w") as fw:
    [fw.write(line[: line.find('siteip = ')] + "siteip = \"%s\"" %(siteip) + "\n" if line.find('siteip = ') != -1 else line) for line in fp]
```

Comment: There's no reason to build up the entire input file in memory; open `myfile.py` for writing first, then write each new line as you generate it.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping the line causes this. Read about [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip). Basically, strip is removing all the white spaces in the beginning and in the end from a string.

Change your code to the following:

```py
reading_file = open("myfile.py", "r")
new_file_content = ""
for line in reading_file:
    if (line.find('siteip = ') != -1):
        line = "siteip = \"%s\"" %(siteip)
        new_line = line
        new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
reading_file.close()
writing_file = open("myfile", "w")
writing_file.write(new_file_content)
writing_file.close()
```

Or as @chepner pointed out, if you want to remove the newline character from the end, you can use `rstrip()`, which will only remove white spaces from the end of the string.

```py
reading_file = open("myfile.py", "r")
new_file_content = ""
for line in reading_file:
    stripped_line = line.rstrip()
    if (stripped_line.find('siteip = ') != -1):
        stripped_line = "siteip = \"%s\"" %(siteip)
    new_line = stripped_line
    new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
reading_file.close()
writing_file = open("myfile", "w")
writing_file.write(new_file_content)
writing_file.close()
```